# Python ValueErro: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python-3.x, validation, dataset, mode, supervised-learning

may any one help me in solving the problem

I run a dataset in csv format in python and get following error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

the code is as below:

```
models = []
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM Non-linear', SVC(C=47.1)))
models.append(('RF', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)))
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = cross_validation.KFold(n=num_instances, n_folds=num_folds, random_state=1)
    cv_results = cross_validation.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

When I run this code for acquiring accuracy than I find this type of the erro.

The dataset is of following data style:

```
1   0.072179    1   0.101844    1   0.138726    2   0.275749    2   0.087135
```

waiting for your help and solution

Comment: So what should I do? I am very much worried

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to transform a string of spaces into a float. It's most likely an error on the parser's end.

Comment: Replace the `msg = (...)` line with debug prints: `print(cv_results.mean())`, `print(cv_results.std())`. I'm pretty sure one of those is, at some point, not a number :)